# How to deal with a "large" number of choices on mobile?

Tags: mobile-web, surveys, progressive-disclosure

I would like to ask a user about his interests. Suppose there are a total of 10-15 (or even more) topics from which the user can choose as many as desired. There might be another section with the same amount of choices.

Which is the better way on mobile devices:

1. To limit the number of topics in advance to e.g. 5
2. To limit the number of topics in advance but provide a "Show more" button. On click the next 5 topics are shown
3. As 2. but on click all remaining topics are shown.

Are there some best practices or other proofen arguments?

Comment: 10-15 don't seem too many to me. Will most of the users want to see the full list or these users will be a minority?

Comment: I don't have any user insights. That's why I have to make assumptions 

Comment: What kind of topics? Could you group the topics to more abstract groups?

Comment: The topics are product categories and brands logos.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some general tips:

Use ***infinite scrolling***. Scrolling is easy on a mobile device. Therefore a "Show More" button is usually less desirable than detecting when a user has scrolled to the bottom of the screen and automatically loading more content.

Choose ***how many items to display*** initially based ***on performance***. Load as many items as you can within a certain (short) time frame. If you can load all the questions as once, it's usually better to do so.

When the user answers a question, automatically ***scroll to the next question*** so they don't have to move their fingers.

Allow each question to be answered using gesture. Such as a swipe left or right interface.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a Hot or Not (tinder) kinda interface, at least that way it's more visually engaging and not just a list with small touch interactions.